# What is the cheapest form of public transportation from Amsterdam to Northern Ireland?

Tags: public-transport, amsterdam, northern-ireland

I'm looking for the cheapest way to travel by public transport from Amsterdam to Northern Ireland (Belfast). I don't care about the time to reach the destination, I just don't know how can I reach Belfast without park in London first.

Comment: I'm assuming walking is out of the question,so I have edited your question to ask only about public transportation options. If I'm wrong, and walking or hitch-hiking are realistic for you, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Stowaway on a ship?

Comment: Ryan Air, if you trust their advertised prices. But, then you'd have to fly with them (and the advertsied prices are garbage).

Comment: Ryanair flies neither to Amsterdam not Belfast. It would have to be Eindhoven to Dublin. And, for this month there are still 23 euro tickets available on that route, with 18 euro tickets for next month.

Comment: Add €27 for the bus Amsterdam to Eindhoven.  Better check out the flights from Amsterdam.

Answer (score 16):

On [megabus.co.uk](http://megabus.co.uk), you can find an Amsterdam - London ticket for 17.50 pounds. Then, a London to Dublin ticket can set you back as little as 15 pounds.
Both connections include a ferry.

Occasionally, Megabus offers deals of 10 pounds for each of the above legs. But, note that trying to book the whole journey as one trip is almost always (if not always) more expensive.

Dublin to Belfast can be had for 8 euros via [Bus Eireann](http://www.buseireannexpressway.com/).

This is certainly not the most pleasant method of travel, but it's damn cheap. If you're lucky, and flexible with your dates, you might get a Ryanair flight from Eindhoven to Dublin for as little as 18 euros. But then you still need to do some peripheral travel.

Comment: Just to add, once you're in Dublin, you can get a train up to Belfast for another €15 (about £11), Dublin is about 100 miles away from Belfast

Comment: I somehow missed that the trip was supposed to get OP to Belfast, edited my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Your cheapest option is *probably* a flight, but this is not certain.  Easyjet appears to have cheap flights between Amsterdam and Belfast, although I'm not sure how many hidden fees are added to their advertised price.  If not flying, between Amsterdam and London, a cheap option is the Dutch Flyer, which will set you back £49:  [Dutch Flyer](http://www.stenaline.co.uk/ferry-to-holland/rail-and-sail/dutchflyer-fares) connects you from any train station in The Netherlands to any in East Anglia including/as well as London Liverpool Street station.  Flying may be cheaper but not usually when counting all additional fees and transportation to and from the airport.

Between England and Ireland, [Seat61](http://www.seat61.com/Ireland.htm) has a rather complete listing.  Apparently, fares start as £39 from London to Dublin by train+ferry, or [53£ to Belfast](http://www.seat61.com/NorthernIreland.htm).  It appears [Busbud has tickets from 42£](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-schedules/London,England,UnitedKingdom/Belfast,NorthernIreland,UnitedKingdom#date=2015-02-06).

You might find cheaper options using buses, as per the answer to the Amsterdam-Paris question, although it seems Eurolines does not serve Belfast, [National Express](http://www.nationalexpress.com/home.aspx) does (but not Amsterdam).  So by bus you'd need at least two different tickets, which makes finding the cheapest option considerably more difficult.

Comment: @pnuts True, although in Europe train stations are almost always downtown and cheaper to get to than airports, and I've never paid extra to take luggage on a train.  So one really needs to look at those costs and check carefully where airports are located, in particular with discount airlines.

Comment: gerrit, do you know if the same works from Paris to Ireland? I agree with you, sometimes the EasyJet taxes are most expensive than pay for a train (because of luggage and taxes/fees)

Comment: @MaxFerreira I guess Eurolines may be the cheapest between Paris and London.  I think there are also ferries between France and Ireland but I suspect they're not cheap, as one probably has to sleep on them.  On the other hand, if that saves a hotel/hostel night it could still help your overall travel budget (ferries from France will bring you to the far south of Ireland, still far from Belfast).  You might want to check out busbud, [Ferrylines](http://www.ferrylines.com/), and [Seat61](http://www.seat61.com).

Comment: @MaxFerreira Within the EU (or is it just within the UK?), airlines must include all taxes and mandatory fees in the headline ticket price. And the part that is tax isn't within the airline's control anyway.

Comment: I'm confused if it's best I visit Paris first and then go to London (to reach Dublin/Belfast) or if it's best I go straight to London from Amsterdam and then see what can I do to reach Belfast/Dublin.
Looks like the best way to make it cheap is go to London first. Right?

Answer (score 3):

I just checked several flight options.
EasyJet, if you do not need to bring luggage, starts from €32, a few months from now. That is including all taxes but excluding all extras you can avoid, like luggage and from Schiphol, so €2.10 for a bus ticket needs to be added. Not sure how much extra for the Belfast end, Belfast International.

Eurolines London to Belfast on the day I tried is already £30, which is quite a bit more than the basic price for EasyJet Amsterdam to Belfast. And you need to get to London first.
Megabus does not seem to include Belfast these days.
But when booking on short notice the price do not get much higher while flights do get more expensive at the drop of a hat.

In short, search all options, the final price depends on the day you book more than on the actual mode of travel.